# Need help drawing line on canvas using html

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw a line on a canvas. I am able to draw the line but I want to be able to draw it dynamically.

Here is what I was thinking:

As soon as the left mouse button is clicked, I get the location of the mouse and store in variables x1,y1. Set downflag = true.

Then if the left mouse button is clicked and the user is dragging the mouse, I continuously get the location of the mouse and store in x2,y2. I was hoping to use stroke() here to update the line continuously but doesnt seem to work? Any ideas??.

Then once the left mouse button is released, get the final location of the mouse and store in x2,y2. Use stroke to draw the path.

Sorry I am bad at explaining what I am looking for..

k

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div style="border: 1px solid blue;">
    <p><strong>Tip:</strong> Click, Drag, Release</p>   
    <p id='coordinates'>null, null</p>
    <p id='downcoord'>undefined, undefined</p>  
    <p id='upcoord'>undefined, undefined</p>
</div>

<canvas width="500" height="500" onmousemove="coords(event)" onmousedown="mousedown(event)" onmouseup="mouseup(event)" id="myCanvas" style="position: absolute; border: 1px solid black;"> Your browser does not support the canvas element. </canvas>

<script>
 var x1,y1;
 var x2,y2; 
 var coorx,coory;
 var downflag;
 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

 function coords(event){
    if(downflag){ //check if clicked before drag
        x2 = event.clientX-9;
        y2 = event.clientY-200;  
    } 
    coorx = event.clientX-9;
    coory = event.clientY-200; //keep updating x and y coord while moving mouse

    var temp = document.getElementById("coordinates");
    temp.innerHTML = "current coord : " + coorx + ", " + coory;

    var temp = document.getElementById("downcoord");
    temp.innerHTML = "start point : " + x1 + ", " + y1;

    var temp = document.getElementById("upcoord");
    temp.innerHTML = "end point : " + x2 + ", " + y2;
}

function mousemove(event){
    if(downflag == true){
        x2 = event.clientX-9;
        y2 = event.clientY-200;
        ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}

function mousedown(event){  
   x1 = event.clientX-9;
   y1 = event.clientY-200;
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
   downflag = true;   
}

function mouseup(event){
   x2 = event.clientX-9;
   y2 = event.clientY-200;      
   downflag = false;
   ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
   ctx.stroke();
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you're drawing a new, very short line on each mousemove, from the previous position of the mouse to the current one.

You need at least two layers, each one with its own canvas.

The bottom layer is where you finally draw each line. The top layer is empty.

On mouse over, you set downflag, and store the mouse coordinates at x1 and y1. Do not draw anything at this step.

On mouse move, if downflag flag is set, you store the mouse coordinates at x2 and y2, clear the top layer, and draw the line from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) on the top layer.

On mouse out, you clear downflag flag, clear the top layer, and draw the line from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) on the bottom layer.

**Edit**: Code sample (requires jQuery). See it in action at https://codepen.io/locoluis/pen/JVerqO

**HTML**:

```
<div id="arena">
  <canvas id="bg"></canvas>
  <canvas id="fg"></canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
#arena {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: white;
}
#bg, #fg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#bg {
  z-index: 1;
}
#fg {
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: crosshair;
}
```

**JS**:

```
var x1, y1, x2, y2, downflag = false;
var fg, bg, ctxFg, ctxBg;
function pendown(e)
{
  x1 = e.offsetX;
  y1 = e.offsetY;
  downflag = true;
}
function penmove(e)
{
  if(!downflag) {
    return;
  }
  ctxFg.clearRect(0, 0, fg.width, fg.height);
  x2 = e.offsetX;
  y2 = e.offsetY;
  ctxFg.beginPath();
  ctxFg.moveTo(x1, y1);
  ctxFg.lineTo(x2, y2);
  ctxFg.stroke();
}
function penup(e)
{
  if(!downflag) {
    return;
  }
  downflag = false;
  ctxFg.clearRect(0, 0, fg.width, fg.height);
  x2 = e.offsetX;
  y2 = e.offsetY;
  ctxBg.beginPath();
  ctxBg.moveTo(x1, y1);
  ctxBg.lineTo(x2, y2);
  ctxBg.stroke();  
}
function init()
{
  fg = document.getElementById('fg');
  bg = document.getElementById('bg');
  bg.width = fg.width = jQuery(fg).width();
  bg.height = fg.height = jQuery(bg).height();
  ctxFg = fg.getContext('2d');
  ctxFg.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctxBg = bg.getContext('2d');
  ctxBg.strokeStyle = "black";
  jQuery(fg).on('mousedown', pendown);
  jQuery(fg).on('mousemove', penmove);
  jQuery(fg).on('mouseup', penup);
}
window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
```

Comment: thanks makes sense! looking forward to your code snippet regarding the two layers

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it! Works like a charm!